# SANE fails to open scanner device - local IP address change possibly responsible

Tags: sane

I have a Brother DCP-7065DN multi-function device. This device includes a flatbed scanner.

Here is what `scanimage -L` reports for this scanner.

```
device `brother4:net1;dev1' is a Brother Scanner DCP-7065DN
device `brother4:net1;dev0' is a Brother DCP-7065DN DCP-7065DN
device `brother4:bus13;dev1' is a Brother DCP-7065DN USB scanner
```

I'm unclear on the difference between the `brother4:net1;dev1` and `brother4:net1;dev0`. The third one is clearly the USB interface (which I don't normally use). I usually use the first one. This is a minor but irritating issue, so I'd appreciate clarifications or suggestions where to look.

This scanner has been reliable, but I tried using it just now, and SANE cannot open `brother4:net1;dev1`. This is likely because I recently switched from a DSL internet service to a cable internet service. When doing this, I had to add a router in front of the cable modem, since the cable modem only had one Ethernet slot. Since the cable modem has address `192.168.1.1` by default, I had to change the router to `192.168.0.1` so as to not conflict with it. The printer uses a static address. It used to be `192.168.1.20`, but I changed it to `192.168.0.20`. This change may be causing the problem - I had to change it in CUPS before the printer would work.

But I'm unable to discover where SANE stores IP addresses of devices. And furthermore, I don't know where it is getting the list of devices that `scanimage -L` is listing. I suspect this issue is easily resolved by someone who has a better understanding of how SANE works.

Comment: [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SANE) gives a good summary, but it doesn't seem to tell the whole story, some proprietary drivers also have `net` configurations in `/etc/sane.d/<device>.conf`.  Perhaps grep for `192\.168\.` in `/etc/sane.d` and `/etc/sane.d/dll.d`?

Answer (score 5):

So, a little more searching, and it appears that the Brother network devices listed in the `scanimage -L` output shown in my question (the first two lines), are listed in (wait for it):

```
/opt/brother/scanner/brscan4/brsanenetdevice4.cfg
```

This has a symbolic link in `/etc` linking to this file:

```
root@orwell:/etc# ls -lah opt/brother/scanner/brscan4/brsanenetdevice4.cfg 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49 Sep 25  2013 opt/brother/scanner/brscan4/brsanenetdevice4.cfg /opt/brother/scanner/brscan4/brsanenetdevice4.cfg
```

Needless to say, I found this by doing a `grep`. For some reason, Brother wants you to modify this file using the utility `brconfig4`, which is kinda bananas. I.e. the syntax to add a device is:

```
brsaneconfig4 -a name=Scanner model=DCP-7065DN ip=192.168.0.20
```

It seems that the devices `brother4:net1;dev1` and `brother4:net1;dev0`
listed above really are redundant, because this is the contents of `/opt/brother/scanner/brscan4/brsanenetdevice4.cfg` with both those devices:

> DEVICE=DCP-7065DN , "DCP-7065DN" , 0x4f9:0x24a , IP-ADDRESS=192.168.0.20
>
> DEVICE=Scanner , "DCP-7065DN" , 0x4f9:0x24a , IP-ADDRESS=192.168.0.20

So I deleted the first line, corresponding to the device DCP-7065DN, using (to humor Brother)

```
brsaneconfig4 -r DCP-7065DN
```